# Flutter-Alternative of Navigator.of(context).pop(true);

Tags: flutter, textfield

I want to close page and back to main page in the stack after clicking alert dialog "yes" button. My page contains textformfields and when i click icon of textformfield search page is opened. After i click any item of search list i back to form page. And I click back button for alert dialog is shown. And click yes button, the bug occures. 
And if i don't use alert dialog, there is no bug. 
Alert navigates me to main page but search list page is opened again. How can i solve this bug?

My alert dialog:

```
 Future<bool> _onBackPressed() {
return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))),
        title: new Text(ml(context, LC.are_you_sure)),
        content: new Text(ml(context, LC.are_you_sure_quit_query)),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
            child: roundedButton(ml(context, LC.no),
                Theme.of(context).primaryColor, Colors.white),
          ),
          new GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
            },
            child: roundedButton(ml(context, LC.yes),
                Theme.of(context).primaryColor, Colors.white),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ) ??
    false;
  }
```

I use code above to navigate to main page. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

I think youre asking about how to remove/clear previous routes.
There are various ways you can do that.
**1** `Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainPage()),
  (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
);`

**2** `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/route') for named router`

Comment: My screnio:  mainpage->query page->query result page->form page

I want to go to previous page  from form page. I cant give route name because i dont know which page is previous